# Meaning of Scala Double Colon (in context)

Tags: scala

How do I complete the declaration of the val:

```
case class Employee(id: String, name: String)
case class Jobsite(title: String)

val list: ::[Employee :: JobSite] = // complete me
```

This is to help understand how to iterate over it, with say `list.foreach{...}`.

Edit: I restated the same question in a different way.

Comment: Neither of those lines compiles...

Comment: Imagine its a list of the type indicated.

Comment: Can you provide code that actually compiles, including definitions of Employee and JobSite, so that we don't have to imagine what you actually meant and hope we're right?

Comment: I apologize for the current state.  I need to understand it further to improve the question.  Switch Employee and Jobsite out with Strings, it does not make a difference what the class is to understand the syntax.

Comment: `val list = :: [String :: String]` does not compile - and I have never seen this written anywhere.

Comment: @vptheron checkout my edit.  Should be better in conveying what I am looking for.

Comment: I think this question should be closed, it's unclear what the OP wants to achieve, since he asked about code that isn't valid in the given language; And he as also not clarified what his code should do. Therefore nobody will be able to answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case class Employee(id: String, name: String)
case class Jobsite(title: String)
val list = (Employee("1", "Jake"), Jobsite("Facebook")) :: (Employee("1", "Ashton"), Jobsite("Google")) :: (Employee("1", "Kirk"), Jobsite("Typesafe")):: Nil
list.foreach(println)
```

Seems that's what you're asking for.

Comment: That looks pretty good, thanks.  I have to try it after lunch.

Comment: So this returns a `List[(Employee, Jobsite)]`.  Take a look at my edit, I am looking for `:: [Employee :: Jobsite]`

Comment: [Employee :: Jobsite] is not a valid type in scala. :: is an operator